# Using os.walk with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, os.walk

I am trying to walk through a large folder / file structure to find all files on a secondary drive (W:\) that contain a specific string.

Doing this using os.walk works, but takes a very long time (> 20mins) to complete. To speed it up I'm trying multiprocessing using Pool, however when I do it is returning matches out of my local C:\ instead of the W:\

What am I doing wrong that it is searching through the incorrect directory?

I am aware that this could also be done with multithreading, but would rather focus on multiprocessing using Pool for this solution.

```
def search_folders(root_dir):

    locations = {'File': [],
                 'Location': []}

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):

        for file in files:
            if "draft" in file:
                path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                a = path.split("\\")
                file = a[len(a)-1]
                path = path.replace("/", "\\")
                locations['File'].append(file)
                locations['Location'].append(path)
                print(f"Doc found at: {path}")
    return locations


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Started...')
    rootdir = 'W:\\Inventory'

    found_items = {'File': [],
                   'Location': []}

    with Pool(14) as p:
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
            for result in p.starmap(search_folders, subdir):
                found_items.update(result)

    p.close()
    p.join()

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(found_items)
    df.to_excel('C:/temp/found.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: In all logic, multiprocessing or multithreading will slow down the process.

Comment: you still have 2 loops. Why don't use `map()` for each of them?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but this task is I/O heavy so async should be the best way of doing this. Also, you could use pathlib for path operations to make this code simpler.

Comment: multiprocessing makes sense when you could use threading but would be blocked on the GIL. The GIL is released during I/O operations. But beyond that, whether even multithreading will make filesystem operations faster is... very situationally dependent; when the I/O system is your bottleneck, trying to fit more things through it at the same time doesn't make things better.